# Bad math environment delimiter when using \begin{split} and \end{split}

Tags: equations, environments, texmaker, delimiters, split

I have the following equation in Texmaker:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
f_{2}(\tau)I_{\theta}(\tau)|_{W_{2}} & = \frac{8\dot{a}c\lambda \e^{2\tau} (\lambda^{2}-\e^{2\tau})}{v_{0}(\e^{2\tau}+\lambda^{3})(\e^{2\tau} + \lambda^{2})}\left(-\frac{2a\lambda (\(\e^{2\tau}+\lambda)}{(\e^{2\tau}+\lambda^{2})(\e^{2\tau}+1)} - \frac{a(\lambda+1)}{(\e^{2\tau}+1)} + \frac{2c\lambda(\lambda^{2}-\e^{2\tau})}{(\e^{2\tau}+\lambda^{2})(\e^{2\tau}+\lambda)}\right) \\
& + \frac{16\dot{b}a c \lambda^{2} \e^{2\tau}}{vb(\e^{2\tau} + \lambda^{3})(\e^{2\tau} + \lambda^{2})} \left( \frac{(\lambda^{2} - \e^{2\tau})(\e^{2\tau} + \lambda)}{(\e^{2\tau} + 1)(\e^{2\tau} + \lambda^{2})} + \frac{(\lambda - \e^{2\tau})}{\e^{2\tau} + 1} + \frac{4c \lambda^{2} \e^{2\tau}}{a(\e^{2\tau} + \lambda)(\e^{2\tau} + \lambda^{2})} \right)
\label{f2Ithetamod}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

When I compile, I get the error message " LaTeX Error: Bad math environment delimiter." However the PDF file produced is fine.

How do I correct this error? Thanks.

Comment: It looks like your code contains a typo, a `\(` that should probably be a `(`, in the first line, where it says `\left(-\frac{2a\lambda (\(\e^{2\tau}+\lambda)}` etc.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution, with `multlined` from `mathtools` and `fleqn` from `nccmath` (the analog of the `fleqn` option, but for a single group of equations), combined with `geometry`, to have sensible outer margins (this supposes you don't use too wide margin notes):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}
\usepackage{geometry}
\newcommand\e{\mathrm e}
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.3pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{fleqn}[2em]
\begin{equation}
\begin{multlined}
  f_{2}(\tau)I_{\theta}(\tau)\mid{W_{2}} =\\
 \frac{8\dot{a}c\lambda \e^{2\tau} (\lambda^{2}-\e^{2\tau})}{v_{0}(\e^{2\tau}+\lambda^{3})(\e^{2\tau} + \lambda^{2})}%
\left(-\frac{2a\lambda ((\e^{2\tau}+\lambda)}{(\e^{2\tau}+\lambda^{2})(\e^{2\tau}+1)} - \frac{a(\lambda+1)}{(\e^{2\tau}+1)} + \frac{2c\lambda(\lambda^{2}-\e^{2\tau})}{(\e^{2\tau}+\lambda^{2})(\e^{2\tau}+\lambda)}\right) \\%
 + \frac{16\dot{b}a c \lambda^{2} \e^{2\tau}}{vb(\e^{2\tau} + \lambda^{3})(\e^{2\tau} + \lambda^{2})} \left( \frac{(\lambda^{2} - \e^{2\tau})(\e^{2\tau} + \lambda)}{(\e^{2\tau} + 1)(\e^{2\tau} + \lambda^{2})} + \frac{(\lambda - \e^{2\tau})}{\e^{2\tau} + 1} + \frac{4c \lambda^{2} \e^{2\tau}}{a(\e^{2\tau} + \lambda)(\e^{2\tau} + \lambda^{2})} \right) \label{f2Ithetamod}
\end{multlined}
 \end{equation}
\end{fleqn}

\end{document}
```

[image]